# Admob crash in below iOS v6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, admob

I run my app in xcode 5.0 and iPhone Simulator7.0 . App successfully executing with admob mediation sdk integration. the same app when i run in xcode 5.0 and iPhone Simulator 6.0 it is crashing. and try without admob mediation integration it is successfully executing.i added -ObjC in "Other Linker Flags".

The log is:

[image]

how can i do solve this problem?

Edit:

i added all the frameworks @iDev told. and the log shows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3466052 0x2c59d0a 0xc929e5 0x1b9783e 0x1b93c72 0x1b98a4f 0x1b9272b 0x1eb9e9 0x1f1849 0x1eff76 0x1ff17c 0x1b8acf 0xc9309a 0xc90705 0x3467e72 0xc9eca1 0xca14be 0xca2058 0x2eeb3ec 0x2eed515 0x339d833 0x339cdb4 0x339cccb 0x3cc1879 0x3cc193e 0x1b5ba9b 0xa1d56 0x2f45 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

To include AdMob mediation for iOS in you app:

```
1. Add the libAdapterSDKAdfonic.a library to your project and ensure it is listed in the target's Link Binaries Build Phase. 2. Add the following additional frameworks to your target's Link Binaries Build Phase :
CoreLocation.framework
MediaPlayer.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
CoreTelephony.framework (If your app supports iOS versions before 4.0, you can add this as an optional framework.)
EventKit.framework
MessageUI.framework
CoreMotion.framework
libsqlite3.a
libz.a
MobileCoreServices.framework
CFNetwork.framework
```